# Batch script, error Windows cannot find

Tags: batch-file

I've got following code:

```
set sciezka = "%~dp0"
echo %sciezka%
pushd
c:
cd %sciezka%
cd
if exist %sciezka%Data goto nocreate1
mkdir %sciezka%Data
:nocreate1
if exist %sciezka%Data\Results goto nocreate2
mkdir %sciezka%Data\Results
:nocreate2

start %sciezka%script.py %1%
if not exist %sciezka%BoostedFeedManager.exe goto nomove
move %sciezka%BoostedFeedManager.exe %sciezka%Data
:nomove

start %sciezka%Data\BoostedFeedManager.exe %sciezka%Data\configInstruments.json
:end
popd

pause
```

After execute it I've got error "Windows cannot find script.py and BoostedFeedManager.exe"

While executing script there's displaying command `set sciezka...`, but 'cd' displaying empty path. What is wrong with this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that variable `sciezka` is not being defined by your very first command/line `set sciezka = "%~dp0"`.

From what I've just tested if you will change that to `set "sciezka=%~dp0"` it should do the work for the issue you're descirbing

Also rather put path in `cd %sciezka%` into double quotes `cd "%sciezka%"` to avoid issues with spaces in path name.

Hope this helps, let me know if not or any further issue